# Gradle wrapper Tag Mismatch error

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I'm trying to manually configure an Android project using gradle and its wrapper, but I always have the same error.

I can generate the `gradlew` script with the following `build.gadle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6'
}
```

When I launch the `gradlew` script I get an SSL error, here is the stacktrace:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-bin.zip
...............
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1541)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.available(AppInputStream.java:60)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.available(MeteredStream.java:170)
        at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:85)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3408)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:77)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1020)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3335)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3328)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:62)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:524)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1023)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:960)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:479)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2377)
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:461)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(InputRecord.java:172)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1015)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally came up with a solution.
Turns out that downloading the wrapper via HTTPS from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/ doesn't seem to be working correctly at the time.

Then I got in front of another problem, the downloaded archive is corrupted... So the trick is to download the archive from your navigator and extract it manually in the path in the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file and then it works like a charm!

Hopefully, the servers will be fixed soon. I am still wondering if the problem doesn't come from my Java installation, though, I'm running Arch Linux and tried `openjdk8`, `jdk8` and `jdk7` every time I changed the version, either I got one step ahead either the error message and stacktrace was different. I will try on windows and update this post.

**EDIT 1**: Turns out it works perfectly fine on Windows! The problem comes from  my Java installation.

**EDIT 2**: I tried somewhere else on a friend's internet connection and surprise it worked like a charm... The problem is probably my ISP (Free) or the router they gave me.

Comment: I have a very similar issue with the Wifi dongle my PC uses. I simply use wifi via my phone using USB tethering. No more half downloads and network errors!

Comment: please chech this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334872/exception-in-thread-main-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-tag-mismatch-react-nativ

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve the issue by connecting to a VPN and perform a re-sync. The download was successful and the sync to. So it seems we're having a network issue.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer, so OP's issue has been solved and that's the only intention of an answer to help OP. But since the question has been succesfully answered your answer is redundant. Furthermore you dont add some high quality information, so there is no need to post just *something*.

Comment: In my case it was the other way around: disconnecting from vpn solved the problem. Besides of this strange SSLException I have now problem using my VPN. It's definitely a network issue, and for me hard to track down, and this workaround just does it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by replacing https for http:

> https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-bin.zip

to

> http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-bin.zip