# Android Gradle Sync "Tag Mismatch!" error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, build.gradle

From past 3 days i'm unable to resolve Android Gradle Sync "Tag Mismatch!" error. I looked and searched for many solutions but none gave positive output.
I also reinstalled my android studio and re-downloaded SDKs as well but all in vein.

If anyone knows how to fix this error, do let me know

ps, I have attached the image of the picture below and i'm using Android Studio 4.1.3 version

Gradle Sync tag Mismatch Error

[image]

**Build.gradle (app)**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.testsample"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**Build.gradle (project)**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Post your both Gradle files.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun gradle images added.

Comment: Post your code directly don't add images nobody has time for your extra click.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun question updated.

Comment: You don't have any dependencies in your project?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun, its a new project, i created in android studio. plus i have added the dependencies also

Comment: Maybe check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569189/gradle-wrapper-tag-mismatch-error/47810245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, It turns out that the security channel of Kaspersky was blocking the complete download of android studio components.

Disable your Kaspersky, install your android studio and let your components download successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Project *** is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
H:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_281
Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
while using Android Studio.

After I change the JDK location to Android Studio default
Gradle Sync "Tag Mismatch!" error came out.....
I google it, still not know why.
So I have to change the project JDK location back, No "Tag Mismatch",
but warning "Using different JDK locations on different processes"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ff7o.png)

Comment: This was the reason for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It might be for an incomplete download of Gradle. Go to **.gradle** folder (for me it's in user folder ) and delete files under **/wrapper/dists/** . Try to download gradle again.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have Kaspersky installed on my computer and was getting this error when using other people's code, or using GitHub.

I saw this answer online, but I can't recall what the link was at this time.

Essentially you need to:

1. ###### Go to your build-tools install folder

   On Windows, this was at `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\{build tools version}`
2. ###### Now you'll want to make a copy of your `d8.bat` file and rename the copy to `dx.bat`
3. ###### Then you'll want to copy your d8.jar file in the `lib` folder and rename it to `dx.jar`

On Windows, this was at `C:\Users\{YourUsername}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\{build tools version}\lib`